# Establish parent origin for postMessage communication

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain, postmessage, referrer-policy

I have an iframe that is embedded into 3rd party sites and I want those sites to be able to communicate with said iframe through `postMessage`. I'd like to limit the origin that can communicate with the iframe to the originating (instantiating) webpage's origin. I currently achieve this by just appending the origin to the iframe as such:

```
<iframe src = "https://whatever.com/iframe?host=${window.location.href}" />
```

However, I'd like to move away from this method for reasons that are out of scope for this question. As such, I was considering verifying the message through a combination of `window.parent` and `ducument.referrer`. Something like:

```
const originatingOrigin = parse(document.referrer).origin;

document.addEventListener("message", function (message)
{
    if (message.origin !== originatingOrigin || window.parent !== message.source)
        return;
});
```

Is this 1) as secure as when I was passing the URL in myself and 2) foolproof in that there are no cases when document.referrer is blocked let's say, in which case the API would be broken.

So, the range of concerns are:

1. Can document.referrer ever be `null/unavailable/incorrect` in *this setup*. I know its possible to be different if you for example go through a redirect, but given that *my script* will be creating the iframe and setting the src that case shouldn't be a concern.
2. Given that I parse/store the document.referrer, are there any weird tricks other adversarial iframes could communicate/move the iframe (to  confused the window.parent, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that setting Referrer-Policy: no-referrer makes document.referrer not work.